# Rails Multi Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication

My application provides two types of authentication - usual email/password or with facebook account.
Authentication with FB is dealed by separate model "Authentication", which belongs to user.
So when currently logged in with email user logs also through facebook, that just gives him ability to use FB API based features.
But if he doesn't have account and tries to authenticate with FB, that causes a problem. I definitely don't want to force him complete registration, because than I don't see a point in this FB interaction, and all features could be set with FB plugins.
So I have 2 ways of solving that. First, creating User via FB authentication, skip user model validations and just leave email and password fields empty. First question - does it cause some really bad security holes?
And second way - take his email from FB api and generate password automatically.
I would like to choose first approach, but potential securiry issues really concern me.
What would you advice?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think youll have security breaches because, in thesis, u made all the things u needed to close them in your model.

I think u should be concerned about yout DB integrity and the other helpers that u could create in the future that could infer that email or any info that fb does not provide are there.

I think u could make fb provide them reading the data from the auth cookie and made your DB completely filled.